# How to scan the database and match models based on certain attributes? (django)

Tags: database, django, object, filter, matching

I have a model

```
class dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

and a views

```
def dog_matching(request):
    # Create the new dog, starting with data from the previous HTML page 
    name = request.session['name']
    # Fill in the rest of the information on the current HTML page
    if request.method == 'GET':
        type = request.GET['type']
        sex = request.GET['sex']
    # Create an instance of the dog
    dog_inst = dog(name=name, type=type, sex=sex)
    # Save the instance to database
    dog_inst.save()
    # Perform matching and send email
```

When a new dog gets created and saved, I want to find each previous dog in the database where the 'type' matches, and the 'sex' differs. Then for each match, I want to get notified via email that a submission on the website resulted in a match (i.e., an email that says, for example, "Scruffles and JayJay match!".)

How do I perform the matching operation, so that each email I receive corresponds to each match?

I am trying something like this

```
if dog_inst.sex = 'male':
    for dog.objects.get(sex__iexact="female"):
    test = dog.objects.get(sex__iexact="female")
        if test.type = dog_inst.type:
            #Send email (I can find documentation for this)

if dog_inst.sex = 'female':
    for dog.objects.get(sex__iexact="male"):
    test = dog.objects.get(sex__iexact="male")
        if test.type = dog_inst.type:
            #Send email (I can find documentation for this)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Django, you would normally call your model `Dog`. Then you can use `dog` to refer to a dog instance. I have done that in my answer.

The main problem is that you are using `get()` when you should be using `filter()`. I think you'd find it really useful to have a read of the [Django Making queries guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/).

In short, you use `get()` when you want to fetch a particular object.

```
dog = Dog.objects.get(pk=5) # gets the dog with primary key 5
```

After you have saved a new female dog to the database, you want to find all male dogs of the same type as `new_dog`. Here we use `filter()`.

We can filter on sex *and* type instead of checking the type of each dog in the loop.

```
if new_dog.sex == 'female': # new_dog is the dog you have just created
    dogs = Dog.objects.filter(sex__iexact="male", type=new_dog.type)
    for dog in dogs:
        # send email
```